# Is the following application of the distributive law legal?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is the following use of distribution legal?

$(\neg p \vee \neg q)\wedge (p \vee q) \equiv ((\neg p \vee \neg q) \wedge p ) \vee ((\neg p \vee \neg q) \wedge q)$

Comment: yes it is legal

Comment: Is the last letter supposed to be $q$ rather than $p$? If so, then yes, it is completely OK, otherwise the two sides are not equivalent.

Comment: Yes you're right, it is. Thanks, I'll change it right away.